# Is there a Powershell Get-Childitem timeout property?

Tags: scripting, powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to use the GCI cmdlet to get information on many remote computers, some of which are sometimes turned off or unresponsive. Is there a way I can specify a timeout property for get-childitem so that the script doesn't hang for 15-20 seconds every time it hits an unresponsive computer?

Thanks,

Tomek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or wrap your gci in test-connection

if (test-connection $server -quiet){
  gci
  }
else {"Connect failed to $server"}

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean the share is up.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Then the question is how often is the server up but the share unavailable?  Then weight that against the additional overhead of creating a new background job for every gci you do.

Comment: in my case, if the server/computer is up, the share is available so test connection is going to work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do your work in a job, then wait on it using wait-job (which has a timeout argument):

```
$job = Start-Job {Sleep -seconds 60}
$res = Wait-Job $job -timeout 5
if(-not $res) { write-Host "Timeout"}
```